# Logging Javascript Exceptions when Bundling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-logging

I have an Angular app where I am logging exceptions on the client to an API backed by NLog, here is the call that logs.

```
    function postError(message, errorCode, source) {
        var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var error = {};
        error.Error = message;
        error.ErrorCode = errorCode;
        error.StackTrace = source;
        $http.post("/api/error/", error).success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (msg, code) {
            deferred.reject(msg);
            $log.error(msg, code);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Message in this case is the message that would be thrown in the console. THis is working as expected except for one thing. In Production, I am bundling the code using ASP.Net bundler and the callstack is that file. I would like to get the unbundled JS file and log that callstack instead. I don't think this is possible but I am hoping there may be a library or something that does something I can work with.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/source-map#new-sourcemapconsumerrawsourcemap

Comment: @n00dl3 Do I have access to this using ASP.Net bundle?

Comment: If it can produce source-map, I guess you can... But if you have such a map, usually the browser can do this natively (chrome does)